# Regular expression to substitute a pattern in VB script

Tags: regex, vbscript, expression

I am trying to write a regular expression in VB script to substitute some patterns.

My string may contain zero or more following patterns -

```
&USERID
&amp;USERID
&USERID.
&amp;USERID.
&USERID(n)
&amp;USERID(n)
&USERID(n).
&amp;USERID(n).
&USERID(n1, n2)
&amp;USERID(n1, n2)
&USERID(n1, n2).
&amp;USERID(n1, n2).
```

Sample string -

```
C:\temp\&USERID_&amp;USERID._&USERID(4)_&USERID(2,2)..txt
```

If USERID=ABCDEF, then once substituted the resultant string should look like -

```
C:\temp\ABCDEF_ABCDEF_ABCD_BC.txt
```

The number in the bracket denotes the number of characters to substitute. Range can be specified using comma separated numbers. In order to achieve this I wrote a regular expression as follows -

```
"((&USERID\(\d+,\d+\)\.)|(&amp;USERID\(\d+,\d+\)\.)|(&USERID\(\d+,\d+\))|(&amp;USERID\(\d+,\d+\)))|((&USERID\(\d\)\.)|(&amp;USERID\(\d\)\.)|(&USERID\(\d\))|(&amp;USERID\(\d\))|(&USERID\.)|(&amp;USERID\.))"
```

Using VBScript.RegExp I match the pattern and obtain collection of the matches. Iterating over each match object, I substitute either the complete USERID or part of it based on subscript.

The regular expression works fine. BUT it is very slow compared to string manipulation function.

Can above pattern be optimized?

Update:

I accepted the answer which solves one of my problem. Based on the regular expression, I tried to solve another find and replace problem as follows -

I have following patterns

```
DATE
DATE(MMDDYYYY)
DATE(DDMMYYYY)
DATE(YYYYMMDD)
DATE(YYYY)
DATE(MM)
DATE(DD)
DATE(DDMONYYYY)
DATE(MON)
DATE(MONTH)
DATE(YYDDD)
DATE(YYYYDDD)
```

It may have a terminating "." at the end.

```
Function replaceDate(matchString, label, position, sourceString)
If label = "MMDDYYYY" or label = "" then
    replaceDate = "<MMDDYYYY>"
ElseIf label = "DDMMYYYY" then 
    replaceDate = "<DDMMYYYY>"
ElseIf label = "YYYYMMDD" then 
    replaceDate = "<YYYYMMDD>"
ElseIf label = "YYYY" then 
    replaceDate = "<YYYY>"
ElseIf label = "MM" then 
    replaceDate = "<MM>"
ElseIf label = "DD" then 
    replaceDate = "<DD>"
ElseIf label = "DDMONYYYY" then 
    replaceDate = "<DDMONYYYY>"
ElseIf label = "MON" then 
    replaceDate = "<MON>"
ElseIf label = "MONTH" then 
    replaceDate = "<MONTH>"
ElseIf label = "YYDD" then 
    replaceDate = "<YYYYDDD>"
Else
    replaceDate = ""
end if  
End Function


With new RegExp
    .Global = True 
    .IgnoreCase = False
    .Pattern =  "(?:&(?:amp;)?)?DATE(?:\((MMDDYYYY|DDMMYYYY|YYYYMMDD|YYYY|MM|DD|DDMONYYYY|MON|MONTH|YYDDD|YYYYDDD)?\))?\.?"
    strTempValue = .Replace(strTempValue, GetRef("replaceDate"))
End with
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without more data it is not easy to test, but you can try if this performs better

```
Dim USERID
    USERID = "ABCDEF"

Dim originalString    
    originalString = "C:\temp\&USERID_&amp;USERID._&USERID(4)_&USERID(2,2)..txt"

Dim convertedString

    Function replaceUSERID(matchString, n1, n2, position, sourceString)
        n1 = CLng("0" & Trim(n1))
        n2 = CLng("0" & Trim(Replace(n2, ",", "")))
        If n1 < 1 Then 
            replaceUSERID = USERID
        ElseIf n2 > 0 Then 
            replaceUSERID = Mid(USERID, n1, n2)
        Else 
            replaceUSERID = Left(USERID, n1)
        End If 
    End Function 

    With New RegExp
        .Pattern = "(?:&(?:amp;)?)?USERID(?:\((\s*\d+\s*)(,\s*\d+\s*)?\))?\.?"
        .Global = True 
        .IgnoreCase = False
        convertedString = .Replace(originalString, GetRef("replaceUSERID"))
    End With 

    WScript.Echo originalString
    WScript.Echo convertedString
```

For a multiple "label" replacement

```
Option Explicit

Dim dicLabels
    Set dicLabels = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    With dicLabels
        .Add "USERID", "ABCDEF"
        .Add "LUSER", "ABCDEF"
        .Add "ID", "GHIJKL"
    End With

Dim originalString    
    originalString = "C:\temp\&USERID_&amp;USERID._&USERID(4)_&USERID(2,2)_ID(2,3)_&amp;LUSER..txt"

Dim convertedString

    Function replaceLabels(matchString, label, n1, n2, position, sourceString)
        If Not dicLabels.Exists(label) Then 
            replaceLabels = matchString
        Else 
            n1 = CLng("0" & Trim(n1))
            n2 = CLng("0" & Trim(Replace(n2,",","")))
            replaceLabels = dicLabels.Item(label)
            If n1 > 0 Then 
                If n2 > 0 Then 
                    replaceLabels = Mid(dicLabels.Item(label), n1, n2)
                Else 
                    replaceLabels = Left(dicLabels.Item(label), n1)
                End If 
            End If
        End If
    End Function 

    With New RegExp
        .Pattern = "(?:&(?:amp;)?)?("& Join(dicLabels.Keys, "|") &")(?:\((\s*\d+\s*)(,\s*\d+\s*)?\))?\.?"
        .Global = True 
        .IgnoreCase = False
        convertedString = .Replace(originalString, GetRef("replaceLabels"))
    End With 

    WScript.Echo originalString
    WScript.Echo convertedString
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried with couple of input strings. I compared the performance by running a loop against string manipulation version. It works okay.

Comment: Similar to USERID i have some other patterns like ID, LUSER, etc. I avoided mentioning the same in the original query to keep it simple. How can we make the "replaceUSERID" generic? is there any way to pass the value to be substituted as an argument?

Comment: This works fine. This code will reside in a library. Is there any elegant way of passing "dicLabels" to replaceLabels method instead of global scope?

Comment: Based on your regular expression, I tried solving another find and replace problem. See updated post.